# How can I use CSS and JavaScript with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a template code CSS and JavaScript files and I need to use them in my Rails application in order to view a list of items.

How can I insert them into my application?

Comment: Read about [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Answer (score 0):

You insert your styles into the app/assets/stylesheets folder and JavaScript into app/assets/javascript folder.

You can either add the files, or paste the code into application.css and application.js.

Then require them at the top kinda like so:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: where i should require them ?

Comment: in application.css and application.js at the top

Comment: rails already provides the requires for some, so just follow the same format